# Trying to get input from JTextfield and use in another method

Tags: java, swing

Im having issues with trying to store values from a `JTextfield` located in method GuessGame() and put them into an array located in findMiddleNumber(). All i get when the program ends is the last input from the user which is the randomNumber.

Could someone please have a look at my code and see where i'm gong wrong please

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuessGame extends JFrame
{
Container container;
int currentDistance;

int inputGuess;
int lastDistance;
int medianValue = 40;
int middleNumber;
int positionIndex = 5;

private JButton newGame;
private JLabel message;
private JLabel prompt; 
private JLabel numberInput;
private JTextField guessInput;
private int countGuess;
private int randomNumber;



public GuessGame()
{
    super( "Play Guess A Number Game Version 2.1" );
    setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

    countGuess = 0;

    prompt = new JLabel( "A random number between N and 100 has been"
            + " selected." );
    numberInput = new JLabel( "Write your number and press enter key: ");

    guessInput = new JTextField( 5 );
    guessInput.addActionListener( new GuessHandler() );
    message = new JLabel( "The result will be shown here." );


    newGame = new JButton( "Start New Game" );
    newGame.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
        {

            guessInput.setText("");
            guessInput.setEditable(true);

            generateNumber();

        }
    });

    container = getContentPane();
    container.add( prompt);
    container.add( numberInput );
    container.add( guessInput );
    container.add( message );
    container.add( newGame );

    setSize( 380, 150 );
    setVisible( true );

    generateNumber();

}

private void generateNumber()
{
    randomNumber = ( int ) ( Math.random() * 93 + 7 );
    System.out.println( randomNumber );

}        

public void processGuessedNumber( int usersGuess )
{
    countGuess++;

    if ( countGuess == 1 )
    {
        lastDistance = Math.abs( usersGuess - randomNumber );

        if ( usersGuess > randomNumber )
            message.setText( "Higher than correst guess." );
        else
            message.setText( "Lower than correct guess." );

    }

    else 
    {
        currentDistance = Math.abs( usersGuess - randomNumber );

        if ( usersGuess > randomNumber )
        {
            message.setText( "Higher than correct guess." );

            lastDistance = currentDistance;

        }

    else if ( usersGuess < randomNumber )
    {
        message.setText( "Lower than correct guess." );

        lastDistance = currentDistance;

    }

        else
        {
            message.setText( "Congratulations, your guess is correct!" );

            guessInput.setEditable( false );
            countGuess = 0;

            findMiddleNumber();
        }
    }
}
public void findMiddleNumber()
{
    int num_of_guesses = 0; 

    Scanner inputs = new Scanner( System.in );

    int [] testArray = new int[ 20 ]; 

    do 
    { 
        if ( inputGuess != randomNumber ) 
        { 
            inputGuess  = inputs.nextInt();      

        } 
        else  
            testArray[ num_of_guesses ] = inputGuess; 
            num_of_guesses++; 

            if ( inputGuess >= randomNumber) 
            { 
                break;      
            }  

    }  
    while ( inputGuess != randomNumber); 

    middleNumber = testArray[( num_of_guesses)/ 2]; 

    System.out.printf( "\nMiddle is: " + middleNumber);

    finalOutput();
}


public void finalOutput()
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Congratulations, your guess "
        + "is correct." + "\n\n1. Middle number from all guessed "
        + "numbers by the user is: " + middleNumber + "\n\r2. Median "
        + " value of all guessed numbers by the user is: " 
        + medianValue + "\n\r3. A position (array index) of correctly "
        + "guessed number in sorted array is: " + positionIndex, 
        "Final Output", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );  

}

public static void main( String [] args )
{
    GuessGame application = new GuessGame();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

}        

class GuessHandler implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent event )
    {
        inputGuess = Integer.parseInt( guessInput.getText() );
        processGuessedNumber( inputGuess );

    }
}   
}
```

Comment: you have no methods like middleNumber() and game(),pls edit with correct names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to take the input from the user when they are coming and store them. in your `actionPerformed()` which is talking value from `JTextField`, store the these values in a array `test[]`, then you call your `ProcessGuessedNumber`, then if it matches, your `findmidlenumber` is called, which *i don't know why you used to take input from `system.in` and storing them in an array when `inputGuess` matches `randomNumber`,* so obvioulsy your `inputGuess` latest value will be the last one, which is the `randomNumber`.

Take user input in array when he is entering them, the control will automatically move to your `middleNumer()` if it is equal to the randomNumber. so, in your GuessHandler's `actionPerformed()`:

```
 public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent event )
{
    inputGuess = Integer.parseInt( guessInput.getText() );
    test[i]= inputGuess;
    processGuessedNumber( inputGuess );
    i++;

}
```

then use this array to calculate whatever you want, like:

```
middleNumber = test[( i)/ 2]; 
System.out.printf( "\nMiddle is: " + middleNumber);
finalOutput();
```

**`Complete Code`**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GuessGame extends JFrame {
Container container;
int currentDistance;

int inputGuess;
int lastDistance;
int medianValue = 40;
int middleNumber;
int positionIndex = 5;
int test[] = new int[20];
int num_of_guess = 0;

private JButton newGame;
private JLabel message;
private JLabel prompt;
private JLabel numberInput;
private JTextField guessInput;
private int countGuess;
private int randomNumber;

public GuessGame() {
    super("Play Guess A Number Game Version 2.1");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    countGuess = 0;

    prompt = new JLabel("A random number between N and 100 has been"
            + " selected.");
    numberInput = new JLabel("Write your number and press enter key: ");

    guessInput = new JTextField(5);
    guessInput.addActionListener(new GuessHandler());
    message = new JLabel("The result will be shown here.");

    newGame = new JButton("Start New Game");
    newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

            guessInput.setText("");
            guessInput.setEditable(true);

            generateNumber();

        }
    });

    container = getContentPane();
    container.add(prompt);
    container.add(numberInput);
    container.add(guessInput);
    container.add(message);
    container.add(newGame);

    setSize(380, 150);
    setVisible(true);

    generateNumber();

}

private void generateNumber() {
    randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 93 + 7);
    // randomNumber = 45;
    System.out.println(randomNumber);

}

public void processGuessedNumber(int usersGuess) {
    countGuess++;

    if (countGuess == 1) {
        lastDistance = Math.abs(usersGuess - randomNumber);

        if (usersGuess > randomNumber)
            message.setText("Higher than correst guess.");
        else
            message.setText("Lower than correct guess.");

    }

    else {
        currentDistance = Math.abs(usersGuess - randomNumber);

        if (usersGuess > randomNumber) {
            message.setText("Higher than correct guess.");

            lastDistance = currentDistance;

        }

        else if (usersGuess < randomNumber) {
            message.setText("Lower than correct guess.");

            lastDistance = currentDistance;

        }

        else {
            message.setText("Congratulations, your guess is correct!");

            guessInput.setEditable(false);
            countGuess = 0;

            findMiddleNumber();
        }
    }
}

public void findMiddleNumber() {
    /*
     * int num_of_guesses = 0;
     * 
     * Scanner inputs = new Scanner( System.in );
     * 
     * int [] testArray = new int[ 20 ];
     * 
     * do { if ( inputGuess != randomNumber ) {
     * 
     * 
     * {inputGuess = inputs.nextInt();
     * System.out.println("inputGuess:"+inputGuess); }
     * 
     * 
     * } else testArray[ num_of_guesses ] = inputGuess;
     * System.out.println("testarr "
     * +num_of_guesses+" :"+testArray[num_of_guesses]); num_of_guesses++;
     * 
     * if ( inputGuess >= randomNumber) { break; }
     * 
     * } while ( inputGuess != randomNumber);
     */

    middleNumber = test[(num_of_guess) / 2];

    System.out.printf("\nMiddle is: " + middleNumber);

    finalOutput();
}

public void finalOutput() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, your guess "
            + "is correct." + "\n\n1. Middle number from all guessed "
            + "numbers by the user is: " + middleNumber + "\n\r2. Median "
            + " value of all guessed numbers by the user is: "
            + medianValue + "\n\r3. A position (array index) of correctly "
            + "guessed number in sorted array is: " + positionIndex,
            "Final Output", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GuessGame application = new GuessGame();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

class GuessHandler implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        inputGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessInput.getText());
        // System.out.println("inputGuess"+inputGuess);
        test[num_of_guess] = inputGuess;
        //System.out.println(num_of_guess + ":" + test[num_of_guess]);
        processGuessedNumber(inputGuess);
        num_of_guess++;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: if i put that coding in the GuessHandler the 'test and i' come back with with and error so does the 'middle' number statement ...

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what u mean? what error? You are trying to take value in your array in `findmiddlenumber()` function, which is called after values have been processed, so you need to take every input from user, when they are actually entered, keep them in array, and then use at the end to find the middle.

Comment: yep thats it .. the errors are for ' middle number' illegal start of type and 'test and i' cannot find symbol. please help